# Firebase Custom Google Auth Login

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I need to login users with Google Sign On onto Firebase. But since I need to use the Calendar API, I have to do a custom login (and not the one provided through Firebase on default), as I need the Oauth refresh token - which is not provided by Firebase. I have looked at the docs but none seem to work, I am using the below code as of now... can anybody suggest how do I use the token obtained from Google to login/register with Firebase?

```
private const val TAG = "WelcomeActivity"

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    //For Google Sign In
    val RC_SIGN_IN: Int = 9001
    private lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    lateinit var mGoogleSignInOptions: GoogleSignInOptions
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private var firebaseUserID: String = ""
    private lateinit var refUsers: DatabaseReference

    //get data from google signin in handlesigninresult
    private var googleId = ""
    private var googleFirstName = ""
    private var googleLastName = ""
    private var googleEmail = ""
    private var googleProfilePicURL = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)
    //        //For google sign in
    //        configureGoogleSignIn()
    //        setupUI()
      //      enablePersistence()
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("")
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    google_login.setOnClickListener {
        signIn()
    }

    login_welcome.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}

private fun signIn() {
    val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task =
            GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        handleSignInResult(task)
    }
}

private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(
            ApiException::class.java
        )
        // Signed in successfully
        googleId = account?.id ?: ""
        Log.i("Google ID", googleId)

        googleFirstName = account.givenName ?: ""
        Log.i("Google First Name", googleFirstName)

        googleLastName = account?.familyName ?: ""
        Log.i("Google Last Name", googleLastName)

        googleEmail = account?.email ?: ""
        Log.i("Google Email", googleEmail)

        val googleIdToken: String = account?.idToken ?: ""
        Log.i("Google ID Token", googleIdToken)

        googleProfilePicURL = account?.photoUrl.toString()
        Log.i("Google Profile Pic URL", googleProfilePicURL)

        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(googleIdToken)

    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        // Sign in was unsuccessful
        Log.e(
            "failed code=", e.statusCode.toString()
        )
    }
}

private fun enablePersistence() {
    // [START rtdb_enable_persistence]
    Firebase.database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
    // [END rtdb_enable_persistence]
}

private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")

                firebaseUserID = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid
                refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(firebaseUserID)
                refUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                        if (p0.exists()) {
                            val user: Users? = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)
                            //Check if user exists in the database
                            if (user!!.getFirstName() != null) {
                                val intent = Intent(
                                    this@WelcomeActivity,
                                    IntroSplashScreen::class.java
                                )
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                            } else {
                                val usersHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                                usersHashMap["uid"] = firebaseUserID
                                usersHashMap["firstname"] = googleFirstName
                                usersHashMap["surname"] = googleLastName
                                usersHashMap["profile"] = googleProfilePicURL
                                usersHashMap["primaryEmail"] = googleEmail
                                usersHashMap["search"] =
                                    googleFirstName.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)

                                refUsers.updateChildren(usersHashMap)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                            val intent = Intent(
                                                this@WelcomeActivity,
                                                NewProfileData::class.java
                                            )
                                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                            startActivity(intent)
                                            finish()
                                        }

                                    }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                })
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                // ...

            }
            // ...
        }
}

private fun refreshIdToken() {
    // Attempt to silently refresh the GoogleSignInAccount. If the GoogleSignInAccount
    // already has a valid token this method may complete immediately.
    //
    // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
    // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently and get a valid
    // ID token. Cross-device single sign on will occur in this branch.
    mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn()
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            this
        ) { task -> handleSignInResult(task) }
}


override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    //Checks if the Google IDToken has expired, if yes it refreshes by SilentSign in and generates new Firebase Token
    refreshIdToken()
    //Checks if user is logged in to firebase
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    //If logged in then sends to MainActivity
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        startActivity(IntroSplashScreen.getLaunchIntent(this))
        finish()
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    refreshIdToken()
}
```

}

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply, I am signing in using Google Sign In first and then attempting to sign in using the same method given in the link you shared, but Google Login occurs, Firebase has a user in authentication but no user is in the RealTime Database in this function firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String)... adn the screen does not change...

Answer (score 0):

My method of checking if the user exists was incorrect with the currect process being to put the check on Datasnapshot exits or not. If exists then login else register.